# How to get email of user from firebase in Text Widget

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I want to write the **User's email** under the User's name in the Navigation drawer, but I cannot access the email in Text Widget
I used this code for fetching user email id from Firebase but unable to write inside Text

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  firebase_auth.FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = firebase_auth.FirebaseAuth.instance;
  Future<void> signOut() async {
    await firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }


  dynamic user;
  String userEmail;

  getCurrentUserInfo() async {
    user = await firebaseAuth.currentUser;
    userEmail = user.email;
    print(userEmail);
    return userEmail;
  }

  static var chartdisplay;
 
  bool isSwitched = true;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
          child: Builder(
            builder: (context) => IconButton(
              icon: Image.asset(
                "assets/images/menu.png",
              ),
              onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xffe8e5af),
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: false,
        titleSpacing: 0,
      ),
      drawer: new Drawer(
          child: new ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50, horizontal: 30),
            color: const Color(0xffe8e5af),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 46,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/avatar.jpg'),
                    radius: 40,
                  ),
                ),
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Nabia Salman',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                        fontSize: 13,
                        color: const Color(0xff000000),
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      //"${user.email}",
                      "nabia.salman99@gmail.com",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                        fontSize: 9,
                        color: const Color(0xff000000),
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

This is how my screen looks like

[image]

Please help me out in finding the solution for this as I am new to Flutter
Thank you in advance

Comment: If you need to get data from async call just use `FutureBuilder` in your widget tree, provide it with a future `Future<String>getCurrentUserInfo()`, set default data like '', and when snapshot is ready display it with your Text widget. More on `FutureBuilder` here: https://youtu.be/ek8ZPdWj4Qo

Comment: what should i write inside builder of FutureBuilder?
I used future builder but i don't know how to use it yet?
If you could help me out a bit?

Comment: Thank you i got it :)